# Get content size before GZip encoding Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, gzip

I have Spring boot web application with GZip encoding enabled.

Spring boot Version - 3.1.0

Embedded web server is Tomcat

application.properties file

```
server.compression.enabled=true
server.compression.min-response-size=1024

server.compression.mime-types=text/html,text/xml,text/plain,application/json,application/zip,text/css,application/octet-stream
spring.http.gzip.deflate-compression-level=5
spring.http.gzip.buffer-size=65536
```

All are working properly. Now I have new requirement to show download progress in FE application. For that need to send total data size before gzip encoding. As I understood I cannot use Content-Length header, because it send content length after encoding.

I try to set custom header with actual data size. My response is JSON output generate by Java class.

How I achieve this ?

Comment: Most likely it will send it chunked, so there won't even be a content-length.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yes, that is the reason. Then how I get exact content size before encoding ?

Comment: If my assumption is correct, you can't.